# Setting a command in an embed discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have looked and I have tried different things, but I cant seem to find an answer that either makes sense or works. I am new to all this in general, but so far stackoverflow has been amazing!

My question is I understand how to create a hyperlink in an embed, but is there way to the embed to work as button that sends a message rather than open up to the web page.

```
const Google = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Google')
        .setURL('https://google.com')
```

At the moment the following embed will link to google.com but is there a way to set it so it sends a "!help" message into the server (which is a separate command within the bot), like something like `message.channel.send("!help")` I have looked at adding fields and such, but it seems this is the only way to make an embed function as a button/hyperlink.

Comment: That wouldn't work, however, you could set up a system using reaction collectors to listen to certain emojis being reacted to the message and do something through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current way to do this as links are just links. You can achieve something similar by using [awaitReactions()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) to check if the member has reacted to the embed and sending the message that way:

```js
// Send embed here
message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            // Send the message here
        }

        else {
            // Optional: Send a message if they don't react with a thumbs up
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        // Also optional: Check if the reacted before timeout
    });
```

You can find more information regarding reactions [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html).